# Excel sheet translation using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, language-translation, google-translation-api

I have an excel sheet filled with English text, so now I wanted to convert each text to other languages (example:- french) and insert in the next column of the excel sheet using python.

So how to approach this?

I'm currently going through pandas of python.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Make sure you `pip install googletrans-temp`

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator 

# read from an excel file
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/andrewgreatorex/Downloads/test_spreadsheet.xlsx')

# translate a column to French, and add back into the DataFrame
translator = Translator()         
df['French'] = df['text'].apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='fr').apply(getattr, args=('text',))

# output new excel file
df.to_excel('name_of_your_output_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks Andy!!! But sometimes it works fine and sometimes I'm getting "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value" can I know the reason for it. If I get this error then it is not working at all.

Comment: df['French'] = df['text'].apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='fr').apply(getattr, args=('text',))..... 
If once it comes then the code  doesn't run at all and throws same error

Comment: Came to know that this error is because of character limit that Google translate has 15k.

How to overcome this? 
Should I change the code?

Comment: Try using a different translation package, https://pypi.org/project/translate/ looks like it might do the trick

Comment: Yes it works!! But even this has a limit for translation same as Google translate API.