# Python: translating a Excel sheet from Chinese to English

Tags: python, translation, keyerror

I am new to Python and I am trying to translate a Excel Sheet from Chinese to English. Id love to have a drag and drop field to load the Data Source but I am trying to get it to work first.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator 

# read from an excel file
df = pd.read_excel('TestBericht.xlsx')

# translate a column to English, and add back into the DataFrame
translator = Translator()         
df['transKunde'] = df['F9'].apply(translator.translate,src='zh-CN',dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))

# output new excel file
df.to_excel('translatedFile.xlsx')
```

Now if I run the code it throws me a KeyError:

```
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'F9'
Desktop\Uebersetzer.py", line 10, in <module>
    df['transKunde'] = df['F9'].apply(translator.translate,src='zh',dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
                       ~~^^^^^^
KeyError: 'F9'
```

I have been going through stackoverflow to find a solution but I didnt find anything. The Script I am referring to is from: [Excel sheet translation using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350457/excel-sheet-translation-using-python)

Comment: The error refers, that in your dataframe object is no key named 'F9'. Maybe try to print your df and see whats inside.

Comment: Yes thats correct, when I print df it shows me my Keys. I dont want to name all the fields because its a report. Is there any way I can select the whole sheet to be translated?

Comment: What happens if you try to do df.apply without the key

Comment: It throws me an AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`df.iat[row, column]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat) to access exactly the cells you need:

> Access a single value for a row/column pair by integer position.
>
> Similar to [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), in that both provide integer-based lookups. Use iat if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.

Remember that pandas take the first column and first row as the header/fields of the data. Pandas also uses 0 as the starting index, so your coordinate would be `9-2,F-2` -> `[7,4]` like so:

```py
df['transKunde'] = df.iat[7,4].apply(translator.translate,src='zh-CN',dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I use iat[7,4] the code drops me an Attribute Error: 'float' object has no attribute 'apply' :#

Comment: Can you try `print` the output of `df.iat[7,4]`? Check if it is the data you expected. I'm not sure myself why there would be a float (decimal point) number in the excel file.